# How to use two 3G modems in a RAID-1-inspired way

Tags: networking

To benefit from two 3G ISP's simultaneously, you'd normally pass half the connections through one ISP and the other half through the other. This as somewhat akin to RAID-0 with two disk drives. Does something like RAID-1 exist for this purpose, in the context of unpredictable bandwidth such as with two 3G modems? Ie software that will download a web page TWICE in parallel, once from each ISP, and ignore the copy that arrives last? So as to, instead of gaining performance, gain reliability?

Comment: Linux is not very good at load balancing, which is what you are looking for. You can load balance VPN using bonding very well though. Google bonding. And decide what you want: bonding or failover.

Comment: maybe squid could be patched to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if one of your ISPs is IPv6 only (or you setup it to ignore IPv4), and another one is IPv4 only, browsers will do it by default via [Happy Eyeballs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Eyeballs) technology. This of course requires that site is available via both IPv4 and IPv6 (like Google, Youtube, Facebook, many CDNs etc)

Other than that, [SCTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol) is protocol invented to do that, but is not widely supported